# issue with crop system using jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag, crop

So im creating this crop system to crop an image. i haven't coded the actual cropping part yet just the dragging interface type thing its kind of glitchy when i drag the box and it's all jittery.. it's kind of hard to explain so ill just show this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8kt3/1/)

```
$("#cropper").draggable({
containment: "parent",
drag: function () {
    pos = $(this).position();


    $('#cropper img').css('left', '-' + pos.left + 'px');
    $('#cropper img').css('top', '-' + pos.top + 'px');

}
```

});

Comment: Fixed the fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/bVk44/ . It seems to work fine? What browser are you using?

Comment: i'd prefer to stick with jquery ui

Comment: for some reason the image inside the box is still jittery when dragged :/